Is steady state ac circuit analysis possible on a purely inductive circuit?
Is steady state ac circuit analysis possible on a purely inductive circuit?  Consider the circuit:

The dynamics should be:
$$
v_1 = L i^\prime + Ri + v_2\\
i(0) = i_0
$$
Now, say we do steady state ac analysis on this circuit, we have that
$$
v_1 = j X_L i + R i + v_2
$$
If we let \$v = v_1-v_2\$, we have that
$$\begin{align}
i &= \frac{v}{R + j X_L}\\
&=\frac{v_R + v_I X_L}{R^2 + X_L^2} + j \frac{v_IR-v_R X_L}{R^2+X_L^2}
\end{align}$$
where \$v = v_R + j v_I\$.  This tells us that
$$\begin{align}
|i| &= \frac{1}{R^2+X_L^2}\sqrt{(v_RR + v_I X_L)^2 + (v_I R - v_R X_L)^2}\\
arg(i) &= \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{v_I R - v_R X_L}{v_R R + v_I X_L}\right)
\end{align}$$
Now, say we check this numerically.  If we let L=0.01, R=0.1, f=3, |v1|=5, |v2|=5, \$\theta_1\$=0, \$\theta_2\$=0.01, i(0)=10, we get the following solve:

Here, isteady is the steady state solution.  In any case, given the initial condition, we can see the current eventually converge to the steady state solution, which is what is supposed to happen.
Now, say we zero out the resistor and create a purely inductive circuit.  We get the following solve.

Here, they don't match.  That's fine, but what assumption behind steady state ac circuit analysis has been violated in the purely inductive case?  The solution is still sinusoidal albeit with a constant offset.  Is this not considered a steady state solution?  Thanks for the help.


The solution is still sinusoidal albeit with a constant offset. Is this not considered a steady state solution?

The solution is always the sum of two components, the steady state, and the initial transient.
All that happened when you set the resistor to zero was that the initial transient went on indefinitely.
Try starting your simulation at different phases of the input waveform, and you will see that you get different transient solutions persisting.
